# Restrict access to objects in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc

I would like to restrict access to objects stored in an Amazon S3 bucket.

I would like to allow all the users on our LAN (they may or may not have amazon credentials since the entire infrastructure is not on AWS). I have seen some discussion around IP address filtering and VPC endpoint. Can someone please help me here? I am not sure if I can use VPC endpoint since all users on our lan are not in Amazon VPC.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What is the authentication provider do you use?

Comment: we are using ADFS.

Comment: How do you define "users on our LAN"? You could restrict access by IP address or you can grant access to authenticated AWS users. Do you have a Direct Connect or VPN connection between your network and AWS? How can AWS identify your "users on our LAN"?

Comment: VPC Endpoint is just for other AWS VPC, not for other connection from your LAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would solve it,

Configure

```
Configure Users from a corporate directory who use identity federation with SAML.
Create Groups
Apply Policies to Group
```

This will give fine-grained control and less maintenance overhead.
This will help you not only to control S3 but any future workloads you migrate to AWS and permissions to those resources as well.

IP based filtering are prone to security risk and with high maintenance in the long run and not scalable.

EDIT:

Adding more documentation to do the above,

**Integrating ADFS with AWS IAM:**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/enabling-federation-to-aws-using-windows-active-directory-adfs-and-saml-2-0/

**IAM Groups:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_groups_create.html

Comment: We are using ADFS.  Let me try to explain it little more. Basically I have a file named index.html in a S3 bucket. This html page has links to other objects in S3. The solution I need is to allow LAN users to access the html page and the links in it. Do I need to create a bucket policy for the user group and attach it to the bucket?  I may be stating something incorrectly as I am new to this. Thanks

Comment: Do I need to use Rotute 53 for this set up?

Comment: Added how you can integrate with ADFS and create IAM groups. Nothing to do with Route 53. Once you have your index.html all linked URLs inside must be relative and not absolute. You can specify which users belong to  IAM group and everything else will be taken care automatically.

Comment: I will try this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your corporate LAN uses static IP addresses. You can create S3 policies to allow access (or deny) based upon IP addresses. Here is a good AWS article on this:

[Restricting Access to Specific IP Addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-3)

VPC Endpoints are for VPC to AWS Services connectivity (basically using Amazon's private Internet instead of the public Internet. VPC Endpoints won't help you with Corporate connectivity (except if you are using Direct Connect).